# How to get a value from a key?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I want to track the bib click, the tracking works, but I need to get `executableitems:ie-id` to check the bib for authenticity.

Here is full item informations:

[image]
[image]

My code:

```
@EventHandler
public void onItemClick(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
   if (e.getAction() != Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK && e.getAction()!= Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR) return;

        ItemStack item = e.getItem();
        if(item == null) return;
        e.getPlayer().sendMessage("Start!");
        if(item.getType() == Material.NETHERITE_CHESTPLATE) {
//      e.getPlayer().sendMessage(String.valueOf(e.getItem().serialize()));
        e.getPlayer().sendMessage(String.valueOf(e.getItem().serialize().get("executableitems:ie-id")));
//      e.getPlayer().sendMessage(String.valueOf(e.getItem().getData()));
        e.getPlayer().sendMessage("Blaze rod clicked!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tag API located in [`ItemMeta`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/inventory/meta/ItemMeta.html).

For some old version, it will be by using `getCustomTagContainer()` then simply use `getCustomTag`. The namespaced key should be `NamespacedKey.fromString("executableitems", "ie-id")`.

For new versions, you should use [`getPersistentDataContainer()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/persistence/PersistentDataHolder.html) then simply use `get` or `getOrDefault`.